# Java: Insert List data into database

Tags: java, sql, arraylist

I have two lists the first one contains columns of the database and the second one holds the data of the first list which is columns. but I have the first list in the manner

```
 colList = [no , name , phone]
```

and
data of that list is in this manner

```
dataListofColumn= 
    [1, Kenit, 999, 2, Kenit, 999999, 3, Kenit, 99999, 4, Kenit, 999, 5, Kenit, 9999, 6, Kenit,9999]
```

When I try to insert the data with this query:

`String sql = "insert into " + tablename+ "("+  colList +")" + " values " + "("+ dataListofColumn+")"`

It gives me error of `ERROR:"INSERT has more expressions than target columns"`

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Your array named `dataListOfColumn` contains more then one row but the sql instruction you are trying to execute is about only one row. Let me add another tip: try to search something about `preparedStatement`

Comment: I tried but I m still getting an error i have also tried query in the loop but it didn't help me. any other approach?

Answer (score 0):

batch insert sql template:
insert into tablename (no,name,phone)values(1, Kenit, 999),(2, Kenit, 999999)...

Comment: But I have dynamic columns and data can please tell me in detail. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder columns = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < dataListOfColumn.length; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0 && columns.length() > 0) {
            columns.append(",(");
        } else {
            if (i == 0) {
                columns.append("(");
            } else {
                columns.append(",");
            }
        }

        columns.append(dataListOfColumn[i]);

        if (i != 0 && (i + 1) % 3 == 0) {
            columns.append(")");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(columns.toString());
```

Comment: What kind of answer represent your previous answer? Plase delete one.